# how to stop a hashtag's default click behaviour?

Tags: jquery, hashtag

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Stop default hashtag behavior with jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2852321/stop-default-hashtag-behavior-with-jquery)

I have some jquery code on a link that loads a DIV into the page using .load(), it also adds a hashtag to the url for pagination / bookmarking purposes; what i want to do is to stop the page from jumping to the div when the link is clicked.

```
$('#jqNav li a').click(function(){

    if($(this).parent().is(".nav1")){ $('.landing .main .nav ul').css({ "background-position" : "0 -50px" });} 
    else if($(this).parent().is(".nav2")) {    $('.landing .main .nav ul').css({ "background-position" : "0 -100px" });}
    else if($(this).parent().is(".nav3")) {    $('.landing .main .nav ul').css({ "background-position" : "0 -150px" });}
    else if($(this).parent().is(".nav4")) {    $('.landing .main .nav ul').css({ "background-position" : "0 -200px" });};


    stopAnim = true;
    $page = $(this).attr('href');
    var $hashTag = $(this).attr('name');
    window.location = "#" + $hashTag;
    loadData();
    e.preventdefault();
    return false;

});
```

Comment: @Michael Irigoyen i already have return false in my code which was the answer to your link, it still passes the problem, note the e.preventdefault(); was just added.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using use `e.preventDefault();` on the link click

Try using `$(window).scrollTop(0);` to prevent the `#` from affecting the page

Comment: This did exactly what i needed it too do thanks Neal!

Answer (score 5):

You can use `e.preventDefault()` for this

http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/

Or use:

```
return false;
```

Which does both `preventDefault()` and `stopPropagation()`

http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/

EDIT

Don't think what you want can be done. Since it would be bad security wise to be able to change the URL of a page without going to that URL.

You can for example change the URL to the URL of a bank letting users think your page represent the bank.

Maybe it works when only adding a hash so you can give the following a try (haven't tested it, might very well not work):

```
window.location.hash = $hashTag;
return false;
```

EDIT2

I know I just told you it doesn't work however I just stumbled upon this post here on SO which uses HTML5 to do what you want:

[Is there a way to change the browser's address bar without refreshing the page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/352343/changing-browsers-address-bar-without-refreshing#4059844)

Again not tested :)

Comment: my code already has a return default, but it seems to jump otherwise see OP for code;

Comment: Thanks this is useful but im not gonna rebuild the whole thing, so neals answer proved to be more appropriate to my needs.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `return false;` as the last statement in the click-handler. That or use both `event.preventDefault()` and `event.stopPropagation()` (`return false` is equal to the both of them together, preventing the default behaviour for that element *and* preventing the event from bubbling up through the DOM).

References:

- [`event.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)
- [`event.stopPropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/)
- [event.preventDefault() vs. return false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/javascript-event-preventdefault-vs-return-false) (at Stack Overflow)