# Preventing page jump - hashed anchor tag - default behavior

Tags: hash, anchor, target, mouseclick-event, page-jump

I made a type of menu box with css click events using targets and link them with hash anchor tags. The problem is, when I click one of the buttons (One, Twii, Thrii, etc.) the page jumps! I tried using a js script to stop the default behavior but to no luck. Could you please help me stop the page jump so the page does not move when a button/link is clicked!

Heres the JS Fiddle link I made. jsfiddle.net/3ASpX/1/

I need a solution..whether its with using target or something else!

Thank You and I apoligize for any confusion in explanation and the question itself if I have done something wrong, your help is much much much appreciated.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2852321/stop-default-hashtag-behavior-with-jquery

Comment: just tried it it didn't solve the issue..thank you although

Answer (score 0):

I think you could do this by using `<div>` instead of `<a>`.

But if you have to use an `<a>`, you could remove the target with jQuery:

```
$( '.link' ).removeAttr("href");
```